# Cast invalid int value to enum

Tags: c++, enums

Say I have

```
enum Foo { Foo0, Foo1, Foo2 };
```

Note that no explicitly declared Foo constant has the value 3 (they are 0, 1, and 2).

Does the following invoke undefined behavior?

```
Foo yay = (Foo) 3;
```

Note expecially that `3` might fit into the internal representation of `Foo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's well defined. In order to represent the value `0`, `1`, and `2`, the type `Foo` has to have at least two bits, and that's enough to represent `3` as well.

Comment: Since C++ isn't Pascal, `Foo0`, `Foo1`, and `Foo2` are just constants; they do not provide an exclusive list of the values that can be stored in an object of type `Foo`.